What is the regularity of a hyperplane in normal coordinates in Finsler Geometry
Let $M$ be a smooth Finsler manifold, fix $p \in M$, and consider the geodesic map $\text{exp}_p: T_pM \to M$. In general, this map is only $C^1$ at the origin. If $H$ is a hyperplane in $M$ passing through the origin, is the set $\text{exp}_p(H)$ (assume the exponential map is injective for simplicity) still in general only a $C^1$ hyper surface of $M$, or does it have higher regularity?
